# Concatenate files into one Dataframe while adding identifier for each file

Tags: python, pandas

The first part of this question has been asked many times and the best answer I found was here: [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe).

But what I essentially want to do is be able to add another variable to each dataframe that has participant number, such that when the files are all concatenated, I will be able to have participant identifiers.

The files are named like this: [image]

So perhaps I could just add a column with the `ucsd1`, etc. to identify each participant?

Here's code that I've gotten to work for Excel files:

```
path = r"/Users/jamesades/desktop/Watch_data_1/Re__Personalized_MH_data_call"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Should the participant number match the number in the filename?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the best thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it's simple:

```py
import re # <-------------- Add this line

path = r"/Users/jamesades/desktop/Watch_data_1/Re__Personalized_MH_data_call"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    participant_number = int(re.search(r'(\d+)', filename).group(1)) # <-------------- Add this line
    df['participant_number'] = participant_number  # <-------------- Add this line
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

That way, each dataframe loaded from an Excel file will have a column called `participant_number`, and the value of that column each row in each dataframe will be the number found in the filename that the dataframe was loaded from.

Comment: it looks like all participants are just being named "1"

Comment: Hmm. Well, I can't tell. can you `print(participant_number)` before it's assigned to the df?

Comment: Yeah, I figured out what's going on, I think. So it would be taking the first digit of the file name which will be the 1 from "Watch_data_1." If use the relative file path, everything seems to work well. Thanks!

Comment: Aha! Funny. Okay, I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Thanks for your help!